# Does compiler remove conditionals on types in templates

Tags: c++, templates

Consider below code:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T a[])
{

    if(sizeof(T) > 1)
        for(...)a[i] = j
    else
        memset(a, j, ...
}
```

I think compiler should remove one of the if-branches in compile-time.
Is it true?

Comment: depends on compiler and optimization

Comment: Why don't you compile it with optimizations with your compiler an see what happens?

Comment: If you're trying to optimize copies by using `memset()` instead of `for` loops for some type `T`, `sizeof(T)` is not an appropriate way to determine if it is eligible for such an optimization. You want to use [`is_pod<T>::value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html) instead of `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: Not only will most compilers optimize the statement away (remember to enable optimizations), but they might also issue a warning about the condition being a constant expression.

Comment: @Insilico in our case, T is guaranteed to be unsigned

Comment: @Volkan Sirin: You can make the compiler uphold that guarantee by creating function specializations for all the `unsigned` types and leave the general function template undefined. Thus, if someone tries to pass a non-unsigned type, the compilation will stop with an error.

Comment: @Insilico But that requires duplicating a lot of lines across functions, I want to maintain highly-optimized code only at one place

Comment: @Volkan Sirin: You can always factor out the common code into its own function, or use [`is_unsigned`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_unsigned.html) with [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/enable_if.html) to disable the function unless `T` is an unsigned type. But that's a more advanced technique that you can use once you get your code working.

Comment: @Insilico Unfortunately, I cannot tolarete any function call overhead and boost is not supported in our platform

Comment: @Volkan Sirin: Depending on your setup, the compiler is probably smarter than you think it is. :-) The only way to be sure is to test and profile.

Comment: @VolkanSirin: You think the compiler doesn't implement inlining or something? Usually the person worried most about performance needs it the least. You might want a working program first.

Comment: @GMan: We measured that a function call in that specific place degredates performance seriously. Program is working but it is beyond its time limits.

Comment: If the compiler didn't remove one branch, it would only be because it had a good reason. If you think your compiler's authors are dumb, use a different compiler.

Comment: @VolkanSirin: I'm saying the function call won't be there if you enable full inlining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the compiler can decide if `(sizeof(T) > 1)` will return true or not, at compile time itself, the compiler can emit machine code without any branch if compiled with optimization flag on. So the resultant code will have either `for` loop (or an equivalent code generated out of it), or `memset`. In other words, the resultant code will not have `if-else` block (provided you're using a smart compiler).

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `std::fill` ?

```
std::fill(begin(a), end(a), j);
```

or are you worried that your Standard Library is not optimized enough ?

Comment: we measured that std::fill is significantly slower than above approach

Comment: @Volkan: You probably want to check your compiler settings then. It should be almost as fast, if not faster. (For the latest version of all major compilers)

Comment: @VolkanSirin: I hate to ask but... did you actually profile optimized code ? FIY I am not sure that the compiler will detect the `memset` switch, that would perhaps be a good optimization to suggest though.